# No audio over HDMI on Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics

Tags: sound, hdmi, intel

My Ubuntu 16.04 connected to Philips TV over HDMI - no audio even when forced to switch to HDMI in "All settings - Sound".

System info:

```
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-5500U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 4096 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 3000 MHz 1: 2400 MHz 2: 2590 MHz 3: 2640 MHz
           4: 2399 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.3 driver: intel
           Resolution: 3200x1800@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
Audio:     Card-1 Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Intel Broadwell-U Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-22-generic
```

By the way other PC with nVidia or AMD GPU work fine with this TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was: click on loudspeaker symbol, click on Sound Settings, click on the right arrow until I reached Configuration and then set Profile off.